# CMAKE Compile_Flag

Tags: c++, exception, cmake

I am using CMake to create my VS2012 solution, I need to set a code generation option to compile code in a specific way.

[image]

I need to set the C++ Exceptions to a specific setting.

How do I go about this? So far I've been trying this

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(swaretrievalobjects1000 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "Yes with Extern C functions (/EHs)")

Is this correct or totally wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it, and checked what happens when you do it?

Comment: yep tried it and get an error which stops my build

Comment: So the answer to "is this correct or totally wrong?" seems kind of obvious then... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on the right track

```
IF(WIN32)
    IF(MSVC)
        IF(MSVC_VERSION EQUAL 1700)
            SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(swaretrievalobjects1000 PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/EHs")
        ENDIF(MSVC_VERSION EQUAL 1700)
    ENDIF(MSVC)
ENDIF(WIN32)
```

Is what i used in the end also had to make sure it was in the correct place towards the end of file.

Answer (score 3):

For the newer versions of cmake 2.8.12+ you can use [add_compile_options](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_compile_options):

```
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
add_compile_options(/EHs)
```

alternatively for an older cmake you can set the settings explicitly with,

```
IF (WIN32)
   SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /EHs")
ENDIF (WIN32)
```

And don't forget to delete the *CMakeCache.txt* file.